# Can I set noReset Appium Capability at the test level

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, appium

I am running some automation scripts using Appium, TestNG, and Cucumber in Java. I was just wondering if there was a way to set the value of the noRest cap at the feature file level.

I have to jump between users a lot of my testing. So I currently have noRest=true but that adds a lot of time having to login in for every scenario. I was hoping there is a way to only have the app reset between feature files so that all scenarios in a feature file run in the same app session using the same user.

Is that a possibility?

Note: Appium 2.0 and Java 11